# regex remove first occurence and first next

Tags: php, regex

Hi search the regex version of this code :

```
$val = '<label for="A" >A</label><label for="B"><div>X</div></label><label for="C"><div>Y</div></label>';           
            $firstLabelPos = strpos($val,'<label for="B">');
            $sideB = substr($val,$firstLabelPos + strlen('<label for="B">') );
            $firstLabelPos2 = strpos($sideB,'</label>');
            $result =   substr($val,0,$firstLabelPos-1)
                        .substr($sideB,0,$firstLabelPos2)
                        .substr($sideB,$firstLabelPos2+strlen('</label>'));


result : <label for="A" >A</label<div>X</div><label for="C"><div>Y</div></label>
```

The code find `<label for="B">` and the closest `</label>`. Make a new string with what was before, inside and after.

---

Its how to remove the label around a div by the "for" attribute.
Or you can say, how to remove the first occurrence of `<label for="B">` and the closest occurrence of `</label>`.

If you can also make sur that we dont touch what is inside the `<label...</label>` (could be another label). That will be appreciate for further practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674

Comment: There can't be another label inside because according to your spec the next `</label>` terminates the match (so it can't occur nested inside).

Comment: he should not have another label inside. But some OpenSource forget about it.